# Как организовать ввод с клавиатуры множеств из нескольких интервалов (-∞, 5.7] U [5.8, 8.7] U [9.5, +∞)?

Tags: java

Посоветуйте как ввести с клавиатуры несколько множеств вещественных чисел

1. `(-∞, -4.7] U [3.8, +∞)`
2. `(-∞, 0] U [2, 7] U [8, +∞)`
3. Таких множеств будет несколько. В каждом несколько интервалов. Только такие [] скобки в общем.

Какой тип данных использовать с учетом того, что не известно количество интервалов в каждом множестве и сколько таких множеств будет?

Потом нужно иметь возможность найти пересечение этих множеств. Те сравнивать введенные данные между собой. Как сравнить я тут не спрашиваю. Я спрашиваю какую переменную использовать для множества.

Символ бесконечности вызывает отдельный вопрос. Как его ввести и как обрабатывать? Может заменить на букву b его?

Я предполагаю, что возможно вариантом будет прямо и писать на экране 
`(-b,7.7][8,9][7.7,+b)` потом enter, и далее вопрос "Хотите продолжить y/n". Если ответить у то можно еще задать множество. Если n, то пошло сравнение. 
В общем, какой тип использовать для ввода множества, с учетом неизвестного количества интервалов и количества множеств?

Comment: b - плохо. Лучше i. А еще лучше решать задачу по частям и спрашивать конкретные непонятные части после неудачных попыток их реализовать.

Comment: Вы с консоли вводите, или у вас GUI? У вас будет только комбинация отрезков и лучей?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот вариант решения задачи со следующими предусловиями/оговорками:

1. Интервалы корректны (для реального использования необходимо добавить валидацию для проверки корректности)
2. Предполгается, что все границы нестрогие (кроме бесконечности) и, следовательно, тип границы можно определить из значения
3. Для разделения диапазонов используется символ `U`
4. Для значений бесконечности используется `i`/`-i`

Класс для хранения диапазона:

```
private static class Range {
    private Double from;
    private Double to;

    public Range(Double from, Double to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    //getters, setters ...
}
```

Основная логика:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    List<List<Range>> ranges = new LinkedList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = "";
    while (!s.equals("n")) {
        s = scanner.nextLine();
        ranges.add(parseRange(s));
        System.out.println("Хотите продолжить y/n?");
        s = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    scanner.close();
}
//парсинг диапазона
private static List<Range> parseRange(String line) {
    // делим интервалы по символу U
    return Arrays.stream(line.split("U")).map(String::trim).map(r -> {
        //отрезаем скобки
        String[] pair = r.substring(1, r.length()-1).split(",");
        Double from = parseDouble(pair[0]);
        Double to = parseDouble(pair[1]);
        return new Range(from, to);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
//парсинг числа
private static double parseDouble(String s) {
    return s.contains("i")? (s.startsWith("-")? Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY: Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY): Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

Пример работы:

```
(-i, 0] U [2, 7] U [8, +i)
Хотите продолжить y/n?
y
(-i,+i)
Хотите продолжить y/n?
y
[6,7.8]
Хотите продолжить y/n?
n
```

В результате выполнения кода в `ranges` будет список, состоящий из списков диапазонов:

```
-Infinity - 0.0, 2.0 - 7.0, 8.0 - Infinity 
-Infinity - Infinity
6.0 - 7.8
```